# In Hibernate, how could I set the creation date to a unix timestamp instead of datetime / LocalDate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

my current project uses Hibernate and I have a LocalDate field in the model class, which maps to a datetime column in the DB with the annotation @CreationTimestamp. The creation date is automatically set when the object is created.

Is there some way to set the format of the creation date to a unix timestamp? Is there a parameter which I could add to the annotation @CreationTimestamp to specify it?

Comment: In no way, sorry. LocalDate, datetime and Unix timestamp are three different beasts with no natural conversion between them (except you may throw the time away from the datetime and obrain a LocalDate). My idea for a creation timestsmp would be `timestamp with time zone` in the database and `OffsetDateTime` in Java. I would use Unix timestamp for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The Unix time is the time duration passed since 1 Jan 1970 in seconds.
In java 8 we have instant class from new date and time api to get unix timestamp.

Below line of code you can use to get unix timestamp.

```
long unixTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

Below line of code you can use to convert unix timestamp

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTime);
```